# How can I bulk insert rows only if a compound primary key don't already exist?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have next simple data:

```
INSERT INTO test_table values
(19156a48-5097-412b-8564-ce3e1e430ea3, 1, 2020-12-11 09:21:48.380494),
(c6b91bf3-af67-4557-8c58-cb3664948723, 1, 2020-12-11 09:31:48.380494),
(103f3010-81a7-419c-8b35-6005dd880f07, 3, 2020-12-11 09:21:48.380494)
```

There are three example rows that I want to insert into table. But I want insert one from rows 1 or 2 (any of them) because this rows have same value at column 2; and row 3 will be insert to because only this row has value 3 from column 2.

Do you understand me?

And I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: Is this for Redshift DB or postgres?

Answer (score 0):

In PG you have the "**on conflict**" clause, to do an action when the query has an error:

```
INSERT INTO test_table values
(19156a48-5097-412b-8564-ce3e1e430ea3, 1, 2020-12-11 09:21:48.380494),
(c6b91bf3-af67-4557-8c58-cb3664948723, 1, 2020-12-11 09:31:48.380494),
(103f3010-81a7-419c-8b35-6005dd880f07, 3, 2020-12-11 09:21:48.380494)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
```

just change **id** for the name of the pk col